# Scroll inner_hits in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a document that has nested items, and in some cases I need to query documents that have nested items that match the filter applied in the search and return all nested items that match.

To do this, in the search query I add the value “inner_hits”. In my tests I noticed that it only returns 3 items by default, and to return more I need to add a size, such as “size: 100”, to return 100 items.

It happens that if there are more than 100 items I cannot add a size like 150, nor can I navigate between the results, for example, making two queries one with “from:0, size:100” and another with “from”101, size:50”. In all cases I always have to increase Elasticsearch's "max_inner_result_window” configuration.

Is there any way, like scrolling, to navigate between inner_hits without having to increase the “max_inner_result_window”? Because if I have a thousand records or more, it won't make sense to have to increase this.

Comment: Could you share the query, which you are referring?

Comment: Yes, scrolling option works. Where are you using this query? In a python script?

Comment: @Sivakumar Mahalingam I don't know how to create a query for only the inner_hits of a document, only for all documents that were returned by a query.